# How to obtain properties of mailbox using ews in C# (similar to the output of Get-Mailbox run cmdlet but using ews)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We want to get all the properties of a particular mailbox in some form of collection object using EWS in C# application that is running remotely and then write these properties to a flat file for troubleshooting/support.

EWS connection is thru impersonate authentication who has admin rights on the mailbox for which we want to fetch the properties.

Basically we want to fetch all the properties listed in the below link for a mailbox remotely using ews.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff328629(v%3dexchg.140)

How can I obtain these using EWS in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `ResolveName ()` method to get mailboxes, for example:

```
var mailboxes = ews.ResolveName(email);
if (mailboxes.Any()) {
    var mailbox = mailboxes.First();
}
```